# How to access the demangled auto comment?

Tags: ida, c++, idapython

In this example, IDA has demangled the `boost::fibers::context::active` name normally, and you can access that name with `ida_name.get_ea_name(ea, GN_SHORT|GN_DEMANGLED|GN_VISIBLE)`. But the function name, the destructor `Security_buffer::~Security_buffer()` does not display demangled, and only appears in a readable form as some kind of auto comment on the function. I can't access that comment as either a normal one or a repeatable one. How can I access this type of demangled name via the SDK/Python (or even in GUI)?

[image]

Comment: Try `demangle_name` with `MNG_NODEFINIT`? Maybe post the mangled name for other people to try too...to ensure you get a real answer.

Comment: @AliRizvi-Santiago this is correct!  Post it as as solution and I will accept.